# Angular custom Tabs left/right scrolling does not update element scrollLeft

Tags: angular, tabs

I created in Angular a custom horizontal tabs with left / right arrows showing in case of overflowing.

the component.html file Looks like that -

```
<button *ngIf="isOverflow" (click)="scrollLeft()">Left</button>
<section #scroll>
   <div class="item">Item 1</div>
   <div class="item">Item 2</div>
   <div class="item">Item 3</div>
   <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</section>
<button *ngIf="isOverflow" (click)="scrollRight()">Right</button>
```

This is the test I perform to set isOverflow -

```
isScrollOverflow(): void {
    this.isOverflow = this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollWidth > this.scroll.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
}
```

When clicking the Right button, I perform the following action in component.ts -

```
@ViewChild('scroll') scroll: ElementRef;
...
scrollRight(): void {
    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: (this.scroll.nativeElement.scroll + 100), behavior: 'smooth' });
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    // this.scrollBar.nativeElement.scrollLeft still equals 0
}
```

It works properly and scrolls to the right, but then when I check the value of -

```
this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollLeft
```

somehow the value still equals 0, only after another Right scrolling click the value of scrollLeft is updated to be greater than 0, same thing happens on scrolling left. in addition to that, I noticed that as soon as another event fires (non-related), the value is updated currectly, it looks related to change detection mechanism, the component is using OnPush,

So I tried running detectChanges and MarkForCheck before checking scrollLeft - but no help

I check the value for the sake of disabling the arrow when scrolling is not possible (already on the left/right hand side)

Will appreciate your help

Comment: please share your code that sets `isOverflow`

Comment: does it work correctly if you use default change detection instead of OnPush?

Comment: @BizzyBob No, also wrapping with settimeout doesn't help here

Comment: where do you call `isScrollOverflow()` ?

Comment: @BizzyBob in ngAfterViewInit and  @HostListener('window:resize')

Comment: Can you recreate this behavior in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)?